# ...(up) into the ceiling - Should "up" be included?

Tags: grammaticality

> Startled, the gunman fell backwards, firing (up) into the ceiling.

Is the sentence natural and grammatical with or without "up"?

Comment: English often uses multiple consecutive prepositions, some or all of which can be included or discarded without significantly affecting the meaning. In your case it wouldn't really make any difference whether you included ***up*** or not. We know ceilings are "up" and floors are "down" without being constantly reminded, so it's not exactly "adding meaning". Nor would it make any real difference if he fired ***at*** the ceiling or ***into*** it - but note that in some contexts ***at*** (along with, say, ***toward/s***) might imply he didn't actually ***hit*** whatever he shot at).

Answer (score 3):

I see why you think the direction is redundant - the ceiling must be "up", so why mention it?

It could be argued that one could shoot at a diagonal angle and still hit the ceiling. If you want to paint the picture that the gun was perpendicular to the ceiling, that direction "up" helps do that.

If you wanted to omit the direction, it would be more natural to say that he "fired **at** the ceiling" However, that could suggest it was deliberate, and in your specific example, the gunman fell backwards and accidentally fired into it. I like the way the sentence is written, it explains the cause (he fell), the effect (he fired upwards), and the result (he hit the ceiling).

Comment: It depends what _you_ are trying to express!

Comment: @Englishmaster Read my last sentence again. I think it works best, in this context, with "up". As it is written.